# Does Prisma create a new relationship collection when using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, prisma

Looking at the Prisma docs and they show the example below. In this instance, if I'm using MongoDB and define my schema as per below, does Prisma create a collection for me called `_CategoryToPost` on my behalf to record the many to many relationships?

Or do I have to create my own collection to document this relationship?

```js
model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email   String   @unique
  name    String?
  role    Role     @default(USER)
  posts   Post[]
  profile Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  bio    String
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int    @unique
}

model Post {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
  title      String
  published  Boolean    @default(false)
  author     User       @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   Int
  categories Category[] @relation(references: [id])
}

model Category {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  posts Post[] @relation(references: [id])
}

enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

[image]

[Link to docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma will create the necessary collections when you run the `npx prisma db push` command. You should not need to worry about the underlying structure beyond that.